# Can someone explain why this Angularjs situation with $firebaseArray and $extend won't work?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Ive made a service to extend $firebaseArray. This works as follows i call the array:

```
 vm.customers = new firebaseExtends(firebaseService.customers);
```

And here is the factory:

```
(function(){

'use strict';

angular
.module('100hh')
.factory('firebaseExtends', firebaseExtends);

firebaseExtends.$inject = ['$firebaseArray'];

function firebaseExtends($firebaseArray){

return $firebaseArray.$extend({
    reset: function(itemOrIndex) {
        var key, self;
        self = this;
        key = self.$keyAt(itemOrIndex);
        self.$ref().child(key).once('value', function(snap) {
           self.$$updated(snap);
        });
    }
});

};

})();
```

This is great it works. But i want to add more extends to the factory but i do not understand why this won't work?

Here is the factory:

```
 (function(){

 'use strict';

angular
.module('100hh')
.factory('firebaseExtends', firebaseExtends);

firebaseExtends.$inject = ['$firebaseArray'];

function firebaseExtends($firebaseArray){

var service = {
  withReset: withReset
};

function withReset(){

  return $firebaseArray.$extend({
          reset: function(itemOrIndex) {
              var key, self;
              self = this;
              key = self.$keyAt(itemOrIndex);
              self.$ref().child(key).once('value', function(snap) {
                 self.$$updated(snap);
              });
          }
        });

};

return service;

};

})();
```

And here's how i'm trying to call it, i simply cannot understand what i'm missing. probably simple but can anyone help.

```
 vm.customers = new firebaseExtends.withReset(firebaseService.customers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var service = {
   withReset: withReset()
 };
```